# Changing units project wide from 'Millimeter' to 'Map Units'

Tags: qgis, map-unit

All my units in my project are in millimeter. But I would like to switch  all units to map units at once without clicking every single signature. I also would like to have the possibility to directly switch between units for the whole project.

Is there a way?

[image]

Comment: A Python script?

Comment: be careful as (usually) map unit result in a lot smaller symbol than millimeter (a big point symbol set at 10 millimeter size will be displayed as a 10 meter symbol in map unit (assuming a CRS in meter), that's  0.2mm at 1/50 000 scale...) so you probably still will need to adjust the size of all your symbol individually anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change everything to map units you can open the project in a text editor and do a find and replace:

Find:

```
v="MM"
```

Replace with:

```
v="MapUnit"
```

If it's just for one layer. Find the section in the project file that controls that layer. Easiest with the layer name.

Search for:

```
<layername>your_layer_name</layername>
```

Just above it will be a maplayer tag:

```
<maplayer simplifyAlgorithm="0" minimumScale="0" maximumScale="1e+08" simplifyDrawingHints="0" minLabelScale="0" maxLabelScale="1e+08" simplifyDrawingTol="1" readOnly="0" geometry="Point" simplifyMaxScale="1" type="vector" hasScaleBasedVisibilityFlag="0" simplifyLocal="0" scaleBasedLabelVisibilityFlag="0"\>
```

Which will end with an end tag:

```
</maplayer>
```

So replace all the references within those tags.