# Difference between visual units in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, units

In QGIS 3.10 (Latest LTR) there are several unit types, see image below

[image: example]

What is the core difference between those units, in sense of their visualization behaviour on the Map?

What I noticed by so far, that some features do not always work with *Millimeters*, e.g. `"Geometry Generator"` and therefore you somehow need to switch from one unit to a different one.

On the other hand, you may work with a map, for example in a Print composer, and furthermore, such unit change can cause a huge impact on your visualization outputs.

Hense, I am looking for some kind of transforming strategy/approach that can lead me to the same visualization outcome but with the application of various Units.

Perhaps someone can refer me to any kind of explicit source with explanations.

---

**References:**

- [Changing units project wide from 'Millimeter' to 'Map Units'](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195490/changing-units-project-wide-from-millimeter-to-map-units)
- [QGIS Docs | The Symbol Selector](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-symbol-selector)
- [How map unit affects the caption size in the label in Qgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243876/how-map-unit-affects-the-caption-size-in-the-label-in-qgis/243881)

Comment: Okay, what is the core question here? If there is a relation/ratio between all these units? Or how their "visualisation behaviour" differs?

Comment: I think the question of relation/ratio is rather self-evident, since except for the map units all these units are standardised. So, what do you mean by "visualisation behaviour"?

Comment: generally speaking, there are two categories of units that you shouldn't confuse: let's call them *visualization* and *geometry* units. when you work on the *geometry* level (e.g. the `Geometry generator`), *units* refer to the **underlying coordinate reference frame** (e.g. units of CRS). when you are styling (*visualizing*) your layers, *units* refer to **screen/canvas dimensions** (`Millimeter`, `Inches`, `Points`); within that set of units, however, you can choose to have **sizes in reference to the *geometry* level** (`Map units`, `Meters at scale`) that are then translated to screen dims

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned by @geozelot in comments

> generally speaking, there are two categories of units that you
> shouldn't confuse: let's call them visualization and geometry units.
> when you work on the geometry level (e.g. the `"Geometry generator"`),
> units refer to the underlying coordinate reference frame (e.g. units
> of CRS). when you are styling (visualizing) your layers, units refer
> to **the screen/canvas dimensions** (`Millimeter`, `Inches`, `Points`);
> within that set of units, however, you can choose to have sizes in reference to
> **the geometry level** (`Map units`, `Meters at scale`) that are then
> translated to screen dims